# Reading .pfs file containing coordinates of anatomical structures in chest radiograph

Tags: matlab

I have a .pfs file containing anatomical structures in chest radiograph. The contents of the file are as follows:

```
;
 ; Array sets
 ;
 ; Written on 2002.12.30 (time: 15:06:39) by ??
 ;

{
  [Label=right lung fixed]
  [LineDisplay=0]
  [PointColor=0.000000 1.000000 1.000000]
  [PointDisplay=1]
  [PointMode=Plusses]
  [PointSize=1]
  [PointWidth=6]
  { 380, 76 },
  { 149, 906 },
  { 438, 783 }
},
{
  [Label=left clavicle fixed]
  [LineDisplay=0]
  [PointColor=0.000000 1.000000 1.000000]
  [PointDisplay=1]
  [PointMode=Plusses]
  [PointSize=1]
  [PointWidth=6]
  { 788.211, 98.0585 },
  { 768, 108.538 },  
},

{
  [Label=left clavicle]
  [LineColor=1.000000 1.000000 0.000000]
  [LineDisplay=1]
  [LineMode=OpenContour]
  [PointColor=1.000000 0.000000 0.000000]
  [PointDisplay=1]
  [PointMode=Plusses]
  { 788.211, 98.0585 },
  { 768, 108.538 },
  { 747.789, 116.023 },
  { 726.83, 122.012 },  
}
```

I need to read only the coordinates that come after the line containing [PointMode=Plusses] into a matrix. The above is only a part of the file. In fact the file contains 5 sets of the above text pattern with the number of coordinates after the line containing [PointMode=Plusses] differing across sets. I need to read all these coordinates across all 5 sets in to one matrix of 2 colums, the first column corresponding to x coordinate and the second column corresponding to y coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick hack; it relies on a fixed layout in your file, and no surprises (i.e. structures that you didn't show yet in the example).

So, put the following in a script, change the path and filename to something that makes sense in your case, save and run:

```
    f = fopen('YourPath\YourFile.pfs', 'r');

    output = double.empty(0,2);

    while ~feof(f)
            line   = fgetl(f);
            values = sscanf(line, '  { %f, %f},');
            if numel(values == 2)
                    output = [output; values'];
            end;
    end;
    fclose(f);
```

In the Global workspace, `output` will have the array of (x,y) pairs.

**Later edit** Code was corrected, please check again.